# How to initialize a Kivy TreeView on GUI-init?

Tags: python, kivy, treeview

I am trying to realize a dynamic TreeView where all updates are initialized in kivy and call a function called populate_tree_view(self, tree). The available Tree-View-docs have been a bit cryptic to me regarding this approach...I already fail at filling a TreeView on init of the App. For the following code I get the error:

> name "wid" is not defined

How is that possible? As far as I understand, I refer to self=Widget, and this widget has a TreeView called "wid". Please help me.

My kivi file:

```
<Widget>
  TreeView:
    id: wid
    root_options: dict(text=somename)
```

my python code:

```
class Widget(StackLayout):

    def populate_tree_view(self, tree):
        self.wid.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='My first item'))
        print("done")

# Init GUI
class App (App):
    def build(self):
        App = Widget()
        App.populate_tree_view(tree)
        return App

App().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- You need to use `Clock.schedule_once()` to call your `populate_tree_view()` method. That will delay the call until the `wid` is is available in the `ids`. Put the `Clock.schedule_once()` in the `build()` method just before the `return`.
- To access `wid` you must use the `ids` dictionary (`self.ids.wid.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='My first item')`)
- `App` is a class in the Kivy package. Redefining it as a `Widget` instance (or even as the name of your `App` class) is a bad idea. Just don't set `App =`  to anything and don't use `class App():`.

Comment: Thank you! Your second point did the magic for me :) However, for other fellow readers: Using Clock.schedule_once is not needed to run this...and "App" was just a badly choosen placeholder I just put "App" in for this example. It should only be used as in "class myApp (App)", as far as I can see it at this early stage..